# SetText from a Class to the main XML file

Tags: java, android, android-studio, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to use the `.setText` within a java class to try to change the value of a `TextView` on the `activity_main` XML file, so far i'm getting the `NullpointerExeption` error and I've read that its due an error when declaring my variable. How can i achieve this? Do i need to declare it first at the `mainActivity.java`?

On my activity_main.xml i have a button -> it opens a custom listView -> if you press the 2 item on the list view -> it opens a custom alert dialog -> the custom alert dialog it contains 2 buttons -> if you press the second button -> it has to set the text of a TextView that is on activity_main.xml

Any help is appreciated!

MainActivity.java

```
final TextView KMLabel = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.KMlabel);
```

activity.main.xml

```
   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/KMlabel"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/TVKm"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/TVKm"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#e6c009"
        android:text="KM/H"
        android:textStyle="italic"/>
```

custom.java

```
public class custom extends BaseAdapter{
Context context;
String Item[];
String SubItem[];
int flags[];
LayoutInflater inflter;

public custom(Context applicationContext, String[] Item, String[] SubItem , int[] flags) {
    this.context = context;
    this.Item = Item;
    this.SubItem = SubItem;
    this.flags = flags;
    inflter = (LayoutInflater.from(applicationContext));
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return Item.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {


    view = inflter.inflate(R.layout.activity_items, null);
    //TextView Prueba = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.KMlabel);
    TextView item = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item);
    TextView subitem = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.subitem);
    ImageView image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);
    item.setText(Item[i]);
    subitem.setText(SubItem[i]);
    image.setImageResource(flags[i]);
    return view;
}
```

**viewdialog.java**

```
public class ViewDialog {
public void showDialog(Activity activity, String msg){

    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(activity);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);

     //I'm declaring it like this
    final TextView KMLabel = (TextView)activity.findViewById(R.id.KMlabel);

    Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_dialog);
    dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    Button KmPerHr = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.KmPerH);
    KmPerHr.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            //and calling it this way:
            KMLabel.setText("MLL/H");
        }
    });
    dialog.show();
 }
}
```

LOGCAT:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                     Process: com.example.dell.getspeed, PID: 3925
                                                                     java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                                                                         at com.example.dell.getspeed.ViewDialog$2.onClick(ViewDialog.java:38)
                                                                         at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5721)
                                                                         at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10936)
                                                                         at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22620)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7406)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Comment: Do you have textView Kmlabel inside your dialog?

Comment: No, the textview "Kmlabel" is on the activity_main

Comment: Try my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

`R.id.KMlabel` is on `activity_main.xml` so you have to initialize the TextView from `MainActivity` reference.

```
final TextView KMLabel = (TextView)activity.findViewById(R.id.KMlabel);
```

**Edit:**

You can use callback pattern for this:

**ViewDialog:**

```
public class ViewDialog {

    // interface for callback
    public interface OnSelectListener { 
      public void onOkSelect(); 
    } 

 OnSelectListener mOnSelectListener;

public void showDialog(Activity activity, String msg, OnSelectListener mListener){

mOnSelectListener = mListener;
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(activity);
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
dialog.setCancelable(false);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);

 //I'm declaring it like this
final TextView KMLabel = (TextView)activity.findViewById(R.id.KMlabel);

Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_dialog);
dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
});

Button KmPerHr = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.KmPerH);
KmPerHr.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        //pass to the implementation if not null
       if( mOnSelectListener != null){
          mOnSelectListener.onOkSelect();
        }
    }
});
dialog.show();
}

}
```

**In MainActivity:**

```
// initialize interface 
 ViewDialog.OnSelectListener mOnSelectListener = new ViewDialog.OnSelectListener(){
    public void onOkSelect(){
       KMLabel.setText("MLL/H");
    }
 };
ViewDialog viewDialog  = new ViewDialog();
viewDialog.showDialog(this, "Message", mOnSelectListener);
```

Comment: and how do i call it? to set the text?

Comment: set text to the `Textview` as you are doing previously. You just have to initialize that `TextView` correctly nothing more.

Comment: It keep on throwing the NullpointerExeption error, this is whats im doing, in my Main_activity.java i'm writing final TextView KmLabel = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.KMlabel); nothing else and on my class i'm writing final TextView KMLabel = (TextView) activity.findViewById(R.id.KMlabel); and then i write KMLabel.setText("Something"); But it is not working, is this the way you say ? I'm kinda lost!

Comment: If `R.id.KMlabel` exist in `activity_main.xml` then it will work. Check  `NullpointerExeption` for `KmLabel` or other view.  post your `custom_dialog` xml  code too and update your code with new code.

Comment: Done! updated the post and more details about what i want to get

Comment: That's all i have, final TextView KMLabel = (TextView)activity.findViewById(R.id.KMlabel); on this line i just changed dialog to activity

Comment: Does `KMLabel` initialized on MainActivity successfully?

Comment: Yes, but it says "KMLabel" is never used

Comment: Some words cannot be recognized! :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167971/discussion-between-abu-yousuf-and-daniel-prado).

Answer (score 0):

You have to move your code

```
Button KmPerHr = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.KmPerH);
    KmPerHr.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            //and calling it this way:
            KMLabel.setText("MLL/H");
        }
    });

final TextView KMLabel = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.KMlabel);
    Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_dialog);
    dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
```

below the dialog.show() code because code findViewById only work after you pop up dialog.

Comment: if you are trying the access the component which are in dialog then you have to do that code after dialog showing.

Comment: I changed the order, still doesn't work. I have the activity_main.xml ->it cointains a button -> it contains a custom listview -> if you press second button(item) on the list -> it opens a Custom AlertDialog with two buttons -> if you press button A it has to set the text from a textview in activity.main.xml

Answer (score 0):

Create a Global class  which extends to application class, then create a texview in Global

```
Textview t = null;
```

Then create two static methods  to set and get this textview

```
Public static void setT(TextView p){
   t = p;
}
```

And get it from

```
Public static TextView getT(){
return t;
}
```

Set TextView in your activity ,then access this textview from wherever you want until your activity is alive.

Comment: Could you explain me a little bit more, please?

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below:

MainActivity class:-------

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private TextView KMlabel;
private Button b;
private ViewDialog vd;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.demo2);

    vd = new ViewDialog();

    KMlabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.KMlabel);
    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            vd.showDialog(MainActivity.this , KMlabel , "Your Message" , "Your Text");
        }
    });
}
}
```

ViewDialog class:------

```
public class ViewDialog {

public void showDialog(Context context, final TextView v , String msg , final String text) {

    createYesNoInfoDialog(context, msg, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // do nothing
        }
    }, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            v.setText(text);
        }
    }).show();
}

private AlertDialog createYesNoInfoDialog(Context finalContext, String message,
                                                DialogInterface.OnClickListener onNoListener, DialogInterface.OnClickListener onYesListener) {
    AlertDialog a = new AlertDialog.Builder(finalContext).setTitle(
            message)
            .setNegativeButton("No", onNoListener)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", onYesListener).create();

    return a;
}
```

}

demo2.xml:-----

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="xcxc"
    android:id="@+id/KMlabel"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:text="Create Dialog"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/b"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens since you are trying to call the TextView within the custom alert dialog. TextView only belongs to the MainActivity. You can call or change that only within the MainActivity class. So please try this below.

MainActivity.class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView KMlabel;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        KMlabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.KMlabel);

    }

    public void setTextKM(String string){
        KMlabel.setText(string);
    }


}
```

ViewDialog class

```
public class ViewDialog {
public void showDialog(Activity activity, String msg){

    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(activity);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);


    Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_dialog);
    dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    Button KmPerHr = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.KmPerH);
    KmPerHr.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();
            mainActivity.setTextKM("MLL/H");
        }
    });
    dialog.show();
 }
}
```

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                           Process: com.example.dell.getspeed, PID: 17304
                                                                           java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

Comment: at com.example.dell.getspeed.MainActivity.setTextKm(MainActivity.java:257)
                                                                               at com.example.dell.getspeed.ViewDialog$2.onClick(ViewDialog.java:42)